# Can't change number of vertices/segments on just created mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have a problem with changing segments of a newly created sphere. A window where I can change it is transparent and does not respond to any clicks. This problem is with any mesh I create. There is already another mesh in the project in which no problems were observed.

[image]

Every time I click this window just disappears. Thanks!

Comment: did you try actually clicking on the spinners and not the window itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to reactivate the *Global Undo* option in the *Preferences* > *System*.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that helped. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the not-global undo disabling these options? very weird UI choices here

Comment: @Oli it probably has to do with the fact that editing the primitive mesh requires to do a kind of undo, but I don't know enough to tell more   :/