# settings bar when I add an object wont let me change anything

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, interface, edit-mode

when I add an object, what do I do if I cant adjust the setting in the bottom left corner. I have tried changing my preferences and random stuff around blender and I cant find anything that works. what do I do?

Comment: have you enabled Global Undo in the Preferences?

Comment: where is that located

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147847/cant-change-number-of-vertices-segments-on-just-created-mesh/147851#147851

Comment: thanks it now works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable: **Global Undo**

For 2.8x and 2.9.

*Edit > User preferences > System > Memory & Limits: Global Undo*

[image]